# How do I setup a visual MySQL client if I already have MySQL installed in my system?

Tags: mysql, installation

I have downloaded the MySQL from the following link:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Downloaded the version 8.0.0. I have OS X 10.10.5

Now, I suppose I need to configure a visual MySQL client on my laptop to write queries. For that, I have installed sequelpro (sequelpro.com).

I need help on following points:
- Since there are a number of sample databases which one can use to learn SQL, can you please guide me on few such databases. My objective is to learn advanced SQL.
- Also, how do I configure my client (sequelpro) to connect to that database so that I can run queries.

As of now, I am stuck with the following screenshot with no clue what to do next.
Thanks a lot. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KL45.png)

Comment: In order to help you we would need to know a lot more. Like what type of system are you running, do you have root access. How did you install mysql etc. Based on what you have said, if mysql is installed already and you have access to it you need to now install phpmyadmin and then update the config file to connect to your existing mysql install. If you are running a local host and you are using a server like mamp or wamp xamp you should already have phpmyadmin installed and you just need to go to localhost/phpmyadmin after you start apache and mysql.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have root access.

Comment: What about the rest of the questions? What system? How did you install mysql in the first place etc.

Comment: I have Mac OS X 10.10.5 I installed mysql by going to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and downloaded the version 8.0.0. Is it what you are asking or do you mean something else when you ask system details?

Comment: I created an answer to your question. If this helps you please click the check mark by my answer to give me credit for answering. If you have anymore questions please let me know and I would be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact you said in the comments you have OSX and you installed mysql manually without phpmyadmin I suggest you download and install [mamp](https://www.mamp.info/en/).

[mamp](https://www.mamp.info/en/)

[1](https://www.mamp.info/en/): https://www.mamp.info/en/ is,

> MAMP installs a local server environment in a matter of seconds on
>   your computer. It comes free of charge, and is easily installed. MAMP
>   will not compromise any existing Apache installation already running
>   on your system. You can install Apache, PHP and MySQL without starting
>   a script or having to change any configuration files! Furthermore, if
>   MAMP is no longer needed, just delete the MAMP folder and everything
>   returns to its original state (i.e. MAMP does not modify any of the
>   "normal" system).

Basically it is a fake server that runs on your computer. This will be yours for localhost development. You can use it to serve your localhost php applications, change versions of php and gives you a GUI for mysql which is phpmyadmin.

Once you install [mamp](https://www.mamp.info/en/)

you might need to configure mamp to use the mamp mysql but most likley it will work out of the box. If you do run into any problems make sure you stop the instance of mysql you installed already before running mamp then trying to ran mamp again and it should be using the correct version.